# Is there any general statement for quantum relative entropy involving CPTP maps on only one slot?

Tags: quantum-information

I was searching the internet extensively about some information on the behavior of quantum relative entropy under CPTP on only one slot. It is well known that
$$S(E_1(\rho)\|E_2(\sigma)\leq S(\rho\|\sigma)$$ but I could not find any source if $E$ was different in the slots, for example for the simple case of $E_1=\mathbb I\neq E_2$.

Do you happen to know anything about that?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, it can be *anything*, since $E_1$ and $E_2$ could simply replace the respective input by *any* state you want, so the left hand side can take *any* value, independent of the right hand side.

Thus, there is *no* nontrivial statement one can make in this case.